# How to run (api-request) a static URL in PHP and fetch response?

Tags: php, json, api

I have a static URL for a GET request, which is like - `api.airtable.com/v0/<my-id>/VID?api_key=<api-key>`. When I run this URL in chrome, I see a JSON response. But I want to fetch the response in PHP and work with it. How do I just run this simple api-request and get the JSON response in PHP?

I am a beginner to PHP, so this question might sound very basic to you :) Your help/advice is very appreciated - Thanks!

Comment: use `file_get_contents()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `json_decode()` function to convert your JSON into an array.
See documentation here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

An example would be:

```php
<?php
    $json_data = file_get_contents("https://your-url-here");
    $response_data = json_decode($json_data, true);
?>
```

Now your `$response_data` variable is an array, with which you can work normally.
Don't hesitate to ask if you need more help. :)

Comment: Thanks! I had to add `true` to the `json_decode()` to make it work for me. Aside that, the solution is perfect. :)

Comment: @whitetiger That's my bad, without `true` as the second argument, you get an object, not an array as I said. You can however work with that object in a similar way, but if you're used to arrays, that works too. :)

Comment: No problem @Saphir! Thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 2):

If JSON response is in array then you can use `escapeJsonString()` and `json_decode()` functions as below.

```
$response = escapeJsonString($response);
$response = json_decode($response,true);

print_r($response);
```